# can I define a function on a map[string]interface{}

Tags: go

I have tried

```
 func (m map[string]interface{}) Foo() {
     ...
    }
```

and

```
 func (m *map[string]interface{}) Foo() {
     ...
    }
```

but go test errors with

```
invalid receiver type map[string]interface {} (map[string]interface {} is an unnamed type)
```

so I have to add some more text to keep SO happy here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define a new type to be able to attach a method to it.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyMap map[string]interface{}

func (m MyMap) Foo() {
        fmt.Println("You fool!")
}

func main(){
  m := new(MyMap)
  m.Foo()
}
```

Comment: i note one answer say m MyMap and the other says b *bar. Are these 2 things equivalent - ie the * makes not difference. If it makes no difference why is it allowed - since to a C reader it looks like they mean different things

Comment: Usually is Pointer to allow the method to modify the struct. You can read more about it here: http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values

Comment: Although it is fairly uncommon to use a pointer receiver with a map: the type already contains a pointer to the underlying data structure, so passing it directly is usually what you want.

Comment: Backing up what James said, the Go wiki's [code review comments page](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/CodeReviewComments) says not to use a pointer receiver for a map type (or func, chan, or slice unless you're reslicing it), since it already contains a pointer.

Comment: Well, there are a few cases where you might want a pointer receiver.  For example, when implementing `json.Unmarshaler` for a map type.  Those few cases are the exception though.